# Alternative to doing mysql COUNT

Tags: mysql, count

This is a follow-up questions this this one: [Way to improve or eliminate a mysql COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705668/way-to-improve-or-eliminate-a-mysql-count), about improving a mysql COUNT.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE worker_id = 1 # worker_id is indexed
```

What would be some alternatives here in how to do this count? Secondly, how do larger sites implement COUNTs? Is it usually with a stored-procedure? Cached? Always mysql-queried?

Comment: Sorry, I mean without using **mysql COUNT**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to improve or eliminate a mysql COUNT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705668/way-to-improve-or-eliminate-a-mysql-count)

Comment: @HoboSapiens yes, I just asked that one. This is a follow up on alternatives to that. The only answer shows the way to do it with mysql count.

Comment: If you want to count something with SQL then `COUNT()` is the way to do it. If that's not delivering the required performance then something is wrong with your database or data or server, or you are simply going about things the wrong way. Based on this question and your last there's no way to know.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I figured it out -- posting a new question about it.